# Socket IO event is not listened but can be monitored in android profiler network

Tags: android, socket.io, listen

Using socket io for my app to trigger certain events, I am listening to custom events and able to listen many other of them but one of them is not being listened. Even though I am able to see that event on Android Profiler Network but the listener is not being called.

[image]

The listening method for all the events are same and as I said earlier I am able to listen all other events other than only this event named "pair"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after a long debugging period I got to know the issue was in the json sent from server. Actually there was some text in arabic which was received as `(5DI 'DDG 9DJG H"DGH3DE)` from the server, so the `"` was causing issue in json formatting.

This issue was found from socket io library class `parser.Parser` method `decodeString` on which `JsonException` was thrown, which was not letting the final callback to be called.